# Mixing union types, generics and conditional types causes unexpected "Type is not assignable to type" error

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-generics, union-types, conditional-types

I've hit a problem with type-inference specifically when conditional-types are used within union types.

There may be a shorter way to demonstrate this issue, but I could not find one...

See the problem in action at this [playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=3.9.7#code/PTAEGEHsDsGcEsAmBTATqALgC2aAZpADaGQDu80A5qAAYBKysAroRgDwAqAfDZgJ4AHZAC4AUKIyDcDZq06gAvKCbQUeCskRdFoAMpMAxgcawZLdt1AAfUAFFUqSKjOsA3OIoY0eAIbHQAPIA0i4YoADeoqDR-ELCoADkwQnuAL6int5+uABqPoRMyKGc2pExsSKJye7lAG75hfEcaRnQXqi+-vaOzozmEVExknGJ3U4pg9FoPfE+0Hwtw7j6RibFHDoqahpaOhvIAB5eqrDKqsjq0JqgAPyBIX2soPF5BUWPFlzuongqBhjwGCgeCwFbGWCwEoAClQH3i6y4AEp4rDZGEQXpDODTB8SgNyrCMExUNBQKjzAA6JaKBRKJJBCbpUQgUAAGWQGASpyYsFw8DC5GwoB8oAQAFsBIRcCpAaSlmIJFIIABGHQAIgAgsq1dZQGqAELa9y-aD-WWgMU+ADWyHAyqhyJVETJHOJpM12tA6QMMFgYQMyvidp0lptdod7h9cH9ytC8Nxdu0SnCFXiauCaoANKB6m94gGva5QCyNazWaAAJK6UAAcQCAQAIuIWQA5MjZih+5A+RCgSB4TA4UXwCVSs7m6k0O00bOkLDwAxYYGnABWPLCNA9OpsBu1M9AUrCPNwIplQOp-dAPtHhxzDUY2anACZ9xRQIc-BhCHxB7hYD4xVwUgfD4BVqQ1J8dDKIYpHiBIIMZRUhFAfVIOTSZU0SVDEOpcA0NACDdVQ40-gBIFQ1tJ8HSDSCU0JN1nXlPUIJ1VIvVEKM-SvJ8aJDa1KIjDjfX9J841AYo8KTRjYL1DNs1zRpuMLYswACAAJUAG1sDU6AAQlEIA).

Consider the following `Result<T>`, a union-type used to indicate the success or failure of an operation (with an optionally attached value, of type `T`). For the success-case, I have used the conditional type `SuccessResult<T>`, which resolves to either `OKResult` or `ValueResult<T>` (depending on whether the result should also carry an attached `value`):

```
type Result<T = undefined> = SuccessResult<T> | ErrorResult;

interface OKResult {
    type: 'OK';
}
interface ValueResult<T> {
    type: 'OK';
    value: T;
}
interface ErrorResult {
    type: 'Error';
    error: any;
}
type SuccessResult<T = undefined> = T extends undefined ? OKResult : ValueResult<T>;

function isSuccess<T>(result: Result<T>): result is SuccessResult<T> {
    return result.type === 'OK';
}
```

Let's use it with a simple union type:

```
type C1 = "A1" | "B1";
function makeC1(): C1 { return "A1" }
const c1: C1 = makeC1();
const c1Result: Result<C1> = { type: "OK", value: c1 }; // ALL IS GOOD
```

Now, instead of the simple union type `C1`, which is just `"A1" | "B1"`, let use a union type of complex values, `C2`, in exactly the same way:

```
type A2 = {
    type: 'A2';
}
type B2 = {
    type: 'B2';
}
type C2 = A2 | B2;
function makeC2(): C2 { return { type: "A2" } }
const c2: C2 = makeC2();
const c2Result: Result<C2> = { type: "OK", value: c2 }; // OH DEAR!
```

This results in an error:

> Type 'C2' is not assignable to type 'B2'.
>
> Type 'A2' is not assignable to type 'B2'.
>
> Types of property 'type' are incompatible.
>
> Type '"A2"' is not assignable to type '"B2"'.

If I remove conditional typing from the equation and define my `Result<T>` to use `ValueResult<T>` instead of `SuccessResult<T>`:

```
type Result<T = undefined> = ValueResult<T> | ErrorResult;
```

...everything works again, but I lose the ability to signal valueless success. This would be a sad fallback if I can't get the optional typing to work in this case.

Where did I go wrong? How can I use `SuccessResult<T>` in the `Result<T>` union, where `T` itself is a complex union type?

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=3.9.7#code/PTAEGEHsDsGcEsAmBTATqALgC2aAZpADaGQDu80A5qAAYBKysAroRgDwAqAfDZgJ4AHZAC4AUKIyDcDZq06gAvKCbQUeCskRdFoAMpMAxgcawZLdt1AAfUAFFUqSKjOsA3OIoY0eAIbHQAPIA0i4YoADeoqDR-ELCoADkwQnuAL6int5+uABqPoRMyKGc2pExsSKJye7lAG75hfEcaRnQXqi+-vaOzozmEVExknGJ3U4pg9FoPfE+0Hwtw7j6RibFHDoqahpaOhvIAB5eqrDKqsjq0JqgAPyBIX2soPF5BUWPFlzuongqBhjwGCgeCwFbGWCwEoAClQH3i6y4AEp4rDZGEQXpDODTB8SgNyrCMExUNBQKjzAA6JaKBRKJJBCbpUQgUAAGWQGASpyYsFw8DC5GwoB8oAQAFsBIRcCpAaSlmIJFIIABGHQAIgAgsq1dZQGqAELa9y-aD-WWgMU+ADWyHAyqhyJVETJHOJpM12tA6QMMFgYQMyvidp0lptdod7h9cH9ytC8Nxdu0SnCFXiauCaoANKB6m94gGva5QCyNazWaAAJK6UAAcQCAQAIuIWQA5MjZih+5A+RCgSB4TA4UXwCVSs7m6k0O00bOkLDwAxYYGnABWPLCNA9OpsBu1M9AUrCPNwIplQOp-dAPtHhxzDUY2anACZ9xRQIc-BhCHxB7hYD4xVwUgfD4BVqQ1J8dDKIYpHiBIIMZRUhFAfVIOTSZU0SVDEOpcA0NACDdVQ40-gBIFQ1tJ8HSDSCU0JN1nXlPUIJ1VIvVEKM-SvJ8aJDa1KIjDjfX9J841AYo8KTRjYL1DNs1zRpuMLYswACAAJUAG1sDU6AAQlEIA)

Answer (score 2):

This happens because `C2` is `A2 | B2` type while `Result<C2>` is
`{type: 'OK'; value: A2} | {type: 'OK'; value: B2} | ErrorResult`.

So the problem comes down to the equivalency of `{type: 'OK'; value: A2 | B2}` and `{type: 'OK'; value: A2} | {type: 'OK'; value: B2}`. This seems equivalent until you add more properties into such object. TypeScript doesn't treat this as a special case and considers general case (imagine more properties) that isn't equvivalent.

Let's consider **another example**: `{ x: "foo" | "bar" }` and `{ x: "foo" } | { x: "bar" }`.

> For example, it wouldn't be correct to consider `{ x: "foo" | "bar", y: string | number }` to be equivalent to `{ x: "foo", y: string } | { x: "bar", y: number }` because the first form allows all four combinations whereas the second form only allows two specific ones.

Source: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12052#issuecomment-258653766

Comment: This answer made the most sense to me, so I award you the bounty. It is a somewhat arcane problem that I eventually re-wrote, modelling the `OKResult` instead as `ValueResult<undefined>`, but hopefully this will be useful to someone else.

Answer (score 1):

`type Result<T = undefined> = SuccessResult<T> | ErrorResult;`

needs to be

`type Result<T = undefined> = SuccessResult<T> | ErrorResult | ValueResult<T>;`

then it compiles.

Cheers, Mike

Comment: `type Result<T = undefined> = OKResult | ValueResult<T> | ErrorResult` is probably a better fit here. Yes, I had observed this already... However, this subtly changes the semantics of `Result<T>`, meaning, for instance, that we can assign `ValueResult<undefined>` to `Result<T>` when `T extends undefined`. Not quite right.

Comment: It does make me wonder whether `OKResult` should really just be `ValueResult<undefined>` though. It would certainly make the model simpler. However, I'm hoping to gain insight into the behaviour of conditional types, because at the moment, I'm missing something.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately specifying the return value of a function is not enough. You need to explicitly return the type. Then it compiles.

This **doesn't work**

```
function makeC2(): C2 {
    return {
        type: "A2"
    };
};
```

This **works**

```
function makeC2() {
    const x: C2 = {
        type: "A2"
    };
    return x;
};
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=3.9.7#code/PTAEGEHsDsGcEsAmBTATqALgC2aAZpADaGQDu80A5qAAYBKysAroRgDwAqAfDZgJ4AHZAC4AUKIyDcDZq06gAvKCbQUeCskRdFoAMpMAxgcawZLdt1AAfUAFFUqSKjOsA3OIoY0eAIbHQAPIA0i4YoADeoqDR-ELCoADkwQnuAL6int5+uABqPoRMyKGc2pExsSKJye7lAG75hfEcaRnQXqi+-vaOzozmEVExknGJ3U4pg9FoPfE+0Hwtw7j6RibFHDoqahpaOhvIAB5eqrDKqsjq0JqgAPyBIX2soPF5BUWPFlzuongqBhjwGCgeCwFbGWCwEoAClQH3i6y4AEp4rDZGEQXpDODTB8SgNyrCMExUNBQKjzAA6JaKBRKJJBCbpUQgUAAGWQGASpyYsFw8DC5GwoB8oAQAFsBIRcCpAaSlmIJFIIABGHQAIgAgsq1dZQGqAELa9y-aD-WWgMU+ADWyHAyqhyJVETJHOJpM12tA6QMMFgYQMyvidp0lptdod7h9cH9ytC8Nxdu0SnCFXiauCaoANKB6m94gGva5QCyNazWaAAJK6UAAcQCAQAIuIWQA5MjZih+5A+RCgSB4TA4UXwCVSs7m6k0O00bOkLDwAxYYGnABWPLCNA9OpsBu1M9AUrCPNwIplQOp-dAPtHhxzDUY2anACZ9xRQIc-BhCHxB7hYD4xVwUgfD4BVqQ1J8dDKIYpHiBIIMZRUhFAfVIOTSZU0SVDEKQ3BwDQ0AIN1VDjT+AEgVDW0nwdfEYijP1QAOIMCOg8ponlPUILVDDUhqGJCTdRi0m+ej-SfZiQ2tKiI1EUSryfONQGKfCk2dDj0yCLM7zzeTC2LMAAgACVABtbA1OgAEJRCAA)

Comment: If you can tell me why this matters from the "view" outside the component, the points are yours.

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned by in some of the answers, problem is that you have `A2` and `B2` which are two different types of objects, and although they are same in your case (both have property `type`), you could easily append other properties to one, but not the other, and in that case `Result<C2>` would not be able to differ if the object behind that type is actually correct since `A2` would not be assignable to `B2` and vice-versa.

What you could do (if your resulting types have same properties) is create some kind of base type where `type` is actually a generic union, which would resolve to one of the specific values like so:

```
type BaseType<T extends 'A2' | 'B2'> = {
    type: T;
}

type A2 = BaseType<'A2'>
type B2 = BaseType<'B2'>
type C2 = A2 | B2;

function makeC2(): C2 { return { type: 'A2' } }
const c2 = makeC2();
const c2Result: Result<BaseType<'A2' | 'B2'>> = { type: "OK", value: c2 };
```

or maybe even simpler version

```
type BaseType = {
    type: 'A2' | 'B2';
}

function makeC2(): BaseType { return { type: 'A2' } }
const c2 = makeC2();
const c2Result: Result<BaseType> = { type: "OK", value: c2 };
```

It all depends on your case and whether you can share your types like such, or they are specific.